# MySql - how to calculate count(*) for query with group by?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have the query :

```
select sellers.* from sellers
    left join locations
    on locations.seller_id = sellers.id
    group by sellers.id
    limit 0, 10;
```

Let assume that first query gives me 10 results with a group by, 15 results without a group by.

Now I want to calculate "all results count" for the pagination.

```
select count(*) from ...
```

I tried this :

```
select count(*) from sellers
    left join locations
    on locations.seller_id = sellers.id
    //group by sellers.id;
```

1.WITH "group by sellers.id" I get 10 results with value 1 (it should be one result with value 10)

2.WITHOUT "group by sellers.id" I get one result with value 15 (it should be one result with value 10)

any ideas?

Comment: Your first query is invalid SQL (although MySQL accepts it due to a (mis)feature).  `select *` with `group by` just doesn't make sense.

Comment: You are missing `FROM`

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right, I changed the query. But this is not a problem here....

Comment: @fico7489 . . . It is still a problem.  You have "bare" columns in the `select` that are neither `group by` keys nor aggregated.

Comment: What about using PHP for that?

Comment: @Enzo you mean get all rows from the database and then call count($rows) from PHP?, what if there are more million rows?

Comment: Do you need a laravel/php solution to this or are those tags unrelated? If that query is generated form the query builder then check https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/pagination-with-group-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

select count(*) from (select sellers.id from sellers left join locations on locations.seller_id = sellers.id) as a;

Comment: yeah, that should work, although I am looking for the solution where only select and group by parts would be changed in the initial query, but I suppose it is not possible in that way...

Answer (score 1):

You can put your `SELECT` query inside a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query, this way:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (select sellers.* from sellers
    left join locations
    on locations.seller_id = sellers.id
    group by sellers.id) sellers;
```

Comment: yeah, that should work, although I am looking for the solution where only select and group by parts would be changed in the initial query, but I suppose it is not possible in that way...

Answer (score 0):

I don't approve of your query, but you simply want the count of sellers.  The simplest method is:

```
select count(*)
from sellers;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this should work for "left join" not for "normal join",  But I am looking for the solution with existing joins...

Comment: also if I have more clauses on join it would not work : 
on locations.seller_id = sellers.id and locations.is_primary = 1

Comment: @fico7489 . . . You queries only have `left join`.  If you have another question, you should ask it as a question not in a comment.

Comment: really ??!? what would admin said if I create identically question with "left join" as only difference ????